# JavaFX - Bind ObjectProperty to member inside another ObjectProperty?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

I have a class called `Tree`

```
public class Tree
{
    private Color c;

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return c;   
    }   
}
```

I have an `ObjectProperty`...

```
ObjectProperty<Tree> importantTree = new SimpleObjectProperty();
```

I want to make another `ObjectProperty` of type `Color` that is always equal to `importantTree.get().getColor()`. Whenever the Tree changes, I want the other ObjectProperty to change to that Tree's color.

For example.

```
ObjectProperty<Tree> importantTree = new SimpleObjectProperty();
ObjectProperty<Color> importantTreesColor = ... 


Tree a = new Tree(Color.RED);
Tree b = new Tree(Color.GREEN);

importantTree.set(a);
System.out.println(importantTreesColor.get()); // This should print RED.

importantTree.set(b);
System.out.println(importantTreesColor.get()); // This should print GREEN.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a binding:

```
ObjectProperty<Tree> importantTree = new SimpleObjectProperty();
Binding<Color> importantTreesColor = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
    importantTree.get() == null ? null : importantTree.get().getColor(),
    importantTree);

Tree a = new Tree(Color.RED);
Tree b = new Tree(Color.GREEN);

importantTree.set(a);
System.out.println(importantTreesColor.getValue()); // Prints RED.

importantTree.set(b);
System.out.println(importantTreesColor.getValue()); // Prints GREEN.
```

You can also do

```
Binding<Color> importantTreesColor = new ObjectBinding<Color>() {
    { bind(importantTree); }
    @Override
    protected Color computeValue() {
        return importantTree.get()==null ? null : importantTree.get().getColor();
    }
};
```

if you prefer.

Comment: What's the difference between a binding and a property?

Comment: In general a property can be set, and most implementations contain the actual value. The binding is just something bound to one or more other observable values. See the relevant [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Binding.html) or the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107).

Comment: Awesome, I understand. As always man, you're amazing. I wish I could just absorb all the information you know about JavaFX haha